# The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity. ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So im trying to enable the a dropdownlist of projects to be enabled depending if the user has a project assigned to it. But I keep getting the error as you see on the title... Im using ASP.NET MVC 5 with Entity Framework

Here's some code:

Controller:

```
namespace ReportSystem.Controllers
{
    [AuthenticateRoles]
    public class TimeReportsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ReportsDatabaseEntities _db = new ReportsDatabaseEntities(); //Database Connection

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            var user = _db.Consultants.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == model.Name);

            if (user != null)
            {
                if (user.Password == model.Password)
                {
                    Session["Name"] = user.Name;
                    Session["RoleID"] = user.RoleID;
                    Session["Id"] = user.Id;

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }

            return View("Login");
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var consultantId = (int)Session["Id"];
            var timereports = _db.TimeReports.Where(c => c.ConsultantID == consultantId).ToList();

            return View(timereports);
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var projectMembers = _db.ProjectMembers.Find();
            var projectId = _db.ProjectMembers.First();

            if (projectMembers.ConsultantID == (int)Session["Id"])
            {
                if (projectId == null)
                {
                    ViewBag.ProjectID = null;
                }
            }

            ViewBag.ProjectID = new SelectList(_db.Project, "Id", "Name");
            ViewBag.ConsultantID = new SelectList(_db.Consultants, "Id", "Name");

            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
@model ReportSystem.Models.TimeReports

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ConsultantID)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>TimeReports</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectID, "Project")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ProjectID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TotalHours)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalHours)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TotalHours)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TimeType)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimeType)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimeType)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OnSite)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OnSite)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OnSite)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

SQL Database:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProjectMembers] (
        [Id]           INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [ProjectID]    INT NOT NULL,
        [ConsultantID] INT NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_ProjectMembers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
        CONSTRAINT [FK_ProjectMembers_ProjectID] FOREIGN KEY ([ProjectID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Project] ([Id]),
        CONSTRAINT [FK_ProjectMembers_ConsultantID] FOREIGN KEY ([ConsultantID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Consultants] ([Id])
    );

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Consultants] (
    [Id]       INT           NOT NULL,
    [RoleID]   INT           NOT NULL,
    [Name]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [PayRoll]  DECIMAL (9)   NOT NULL,
    [Password] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Consultants] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Consultants_RoleID] FOREIGN KEY ([RoleID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Role] ([Id])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Project] (
    [Id]           INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]         NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [ProjectId]    NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Image]        IMAGE          NULL,
    [SubProject]   NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Role]         NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [TotalHours]   DECIMAL (9, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectType]  NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Budget]       MONEY          NOT NULL,
    [Orders]       NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [ProfitMargin] NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Active]       BIT            NOT NULL,
    [ProjectStart] DATE           NOT NULL,
    [ProjectEnd]   DATE           NULL,
    [TimeType]     NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [KickBack]     NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Project] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Check how Entity Framework generated your entities, make sure the primary keys and foreign keys are built the way you are expecting them.  Also it looks like your ProjectMembers table has a foreign key to Project but you did not include that table in your post, is that in Entity Framework?  If not, include it in Entity Framework or remove the link from the entity if you are not using it.

Answer (score 0):

Since ProjectMembers table has a primary key, try passing a primary key in the find statement as var projectMembers = _db.ProjectMembers.Find((int) Session["Id"]); Please refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj573936.aspx

Comment: The specified parameter type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[[ReportSystem.Models.ProjectMembers, ReportSystem, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' is not valid. Only scalar types, such as System.Int32, System.Decimal, System.DateTime, and System.Guid, are supported.

var primarykey = _db.ProjectMembers.Where(i => i.Id == (int) Session["Id"]);
            var projectMembers = _db.ProjectMembers.Find(primarykey);

It did not work sir.

Comment: You are trying to pass a collection as a primary key, hence the error. Please see my edited answer.